# radiobutton and edittext beside together for a calculator

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm trying to write a class to calculate density, you can choose density or mass or volume as well. i set as if you choose any of above value related edittext got setEnabled false and when  press calculate button set text in same edittext but it doesn't work please help

it is my java class:
      package ir.kiandroid.chemcalculator3;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;

public class Chegali extends Activity {

    private static final int MENU_ITEM1 = 0;
    private static final int MENU_ITEM2 = 1;
    private static final int MENU_ITEM3 = 2;

    // step1 : create all the variables.
    EditText roe, me, ve;
    TextView sub;
      Button b1, b2;
// String phEvar;
    RadioButton ro, m, vr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chegali);

    // step2 : get all the views from xml file.
    roe = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.e1);
    me = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.e2);
    ve = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.e3);

    ro = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.one);
    m = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.two);
    vr = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.three);

    sub = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subject);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    // /////////
    sub.setText("محاسبه چگالی، ابتدا مجهول را انتخاب کنید سپس متغییر ها را وارد کنید.");
    // ////////
    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            if (ro.isChecked() == true) {

                roe.setText("X=? gr/ml");
                me.setText("");
                ve.setText("");
                roe.setEnabled(false);
                me.setEnabled(true);
                ve.setEnabled(true);
            } else if (m.isChecked() == true) {

                roe.setText("");
                me.setText("X=? gr");
                ve.setText("");
                me.setEnabled(false);
                roe.setEnabled(true);
                ve.setEnabled(true);
            } else if (vr.isChecked() == true) {
                roe.setText("");
                me.setText("");
                ve.setText("X=? ml");
                ve.setEnabled(false);
                roe.setEnabled(true);
                me.setEnabled(true);
            }

        }
    });

    // step3 : write add functionality.
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                String roVar = roe.getText().toString();
                double roDou = Double.parseDouble(roVar);

                String vVar = ve.getText().toString();
                double vDou = Double.parseDouble(vVar);

                String mVar = me.getText().toString();
                double mDou = Double.parseDouble(mVar);

                if (ro.isChecked() == true) {

                    double result = mDou / vDou;
                    result = result * 100;
                    result = (double) ((int) result);
                    result = result / 100;
                    String rec = String.valueOf(result);
                    roe.setText("X=" + rec + "gr/ml");

                } else if (m.isChecked() == true) {
                    double result = roDou * vDou;
                    result = result * 100;
                    result = (double) ((int) result);
                    result = result / 100;
                    String rec = String.valueOf(result);
                    me.setText("X=" + rec + "gr");

                } else if (vr.isChecked() == true) {
                    double result = mDou / roDou;
                    result = result * 100;
                    result = (double) ((int) result);
                    result = result / 100;
                    String rec = String.valueOf(result);
                    ve.setText("X=" + rec + "ml");

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Chegali.this, "مجهول را انتخاب کنید.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(Chegali.this, "همه بخش ها را پر کنید.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    /*
     * 
     * 
     * b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     * 
     * @Override public void onClick(View v) { String f =
     * ph.getText().toString(); int i = Integer.parseInt(f); String s =
     * volum.getText().toString(); int j = Integer.parseInt(s);
     * 
     * Integer result = i-j; String res = result.toString();
     * et3.setText(res); } });
     */

 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_ITEM1, Menu.NONE, "کیان دروید").setIcon(
            R.drawable.kian);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_ITEM2, Menu.NONE, "درباره اپ").setIcon(
            R.drawable.about);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_ITEM3, Menu.NONE, "فیسبوک").setIcon(
            R.drawable.facebook);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case MENU_ITEM1:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "کیان دروید",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case MENU_ITEM2:
        startActivity(new Intent(Chegali.this, About.class));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "درباره این برنامه",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    case MENU_ITEM3:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "فیس بوک",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }

 }
```

and xml file:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/back3"
tools:context=".Chegali" >
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
 >

  <ImageView
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:src="@drawable/top" />
 <View
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="1dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
  android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/subject"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="عنوان"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@drawable/tv2_background"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
 <View
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="1dp"
   android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

 <RadioGroup
         android:id="@+id/rg"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

         >



     <RadioButton 
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="چگالی"              
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right"            
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            />
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/e1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:ems="8" 
    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal|numberSigned"
    android:digits="0123456789."/>
  <requestFocus />



  <View
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="1dp"
  android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

  <RadioButton 
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="جرم"                               
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            />
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/e2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:ems="8" 
    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal|numberSigned"
    android:digits="0123456789."/>

  <View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <RadioButton 
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="حجم"           
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            />
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/e3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:ems="8" 
    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal|numberSigned"
    android:digits="0123456789."/>



  </RadioGroup>




  <View
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="1dp"
  android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right">
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="محاسبه" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="کمک" />

  </RelativeLayout>



  </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```